# Виджет на C#, или Windows Forms Always On Bottom

Tags: c#

Сделал приложение Windows Forms, хочу использовать его как виджет на рабочем столе, но не могу закрепить его так, чтобы оно находилось всегда сзади всех открытых процессов (то есть на рабочем столе). Почитал зарубежные сайты, способы описанные там не работают, может есть какой-то современный вариант это осуществить?

Comment: А можете описать опробаванные Вам способы хоть как-то чтобы, Вам по второму кругу тоже самое не предлагали...ну или может даже приложить, код/настройки...может Вы просто что-то упустили?

Answer (score 1):

В событии Activated формы пишем:

```
private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.SendToBack();
}
```

Это будет постоянно размещать форму ниже всех остальных.

Чтобы форма была постоянно на рабочем столе, отключим возможность её минимизации:

```
this.MinimizeBox = false;
```

Comment: интересный вариант, надо будет попробовать. для хорошего эффекта еще и бордер убрать, чтобы шапка формы не маячила перед глазами

Comment: Прикольно, но не то. Способ работает, если для перехода на раб стол сворачивать все окно по-отдельности, но я нажимаю в правый нижний угол экрана, что сворачивает все окна, включая окно с виджетом. Можно как-то запретить приложению сворачиваться?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно сделать форму, которую пользователь не сможет поместить поверх других. Однако, сама она появляется сверху и будет уходить вглубь по мере перехода в другие приложения.

```
class Form1 : Form
{
  protected override CreateParams CreateParams
  {
    get
    {
      const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000, WS_EX_APPWINDOW = 0x00040000;

      var cp = base.CreateParams;
      cp.ExStyle = (cp.ExStyle & ~WS_EX_APPWINDOW) | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
      return cp;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Способ, чтобы форма всегда находилась на заднем уровне и не заходила поверх других окон:

```
   private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SendToBack();
    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SendToBack();
    }

    private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SendToBack();
    }
```

Однако при нажатии "свернуть все окна" исчезает.